# KeyError: "Couldn't find enum caffe.EmitConstraint.EmitType"

Tags: python, c++, deep-learning, computer-vision, caffe

After installing caffe from source, while running sample test projects I am facing above issue.
What might be the cause of this error.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your caffe version and the version used to train/deploy the model you are trying to use are not the same. More specifically, it seems like the model you are trying to use has some `"EmitType"` parameter in its prototxt. This parameter is not defined in the master [`caffe.proto`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto).

Please make sure you use the same branch of caffe as required by the model you are trying to run.

Comment: I just reinstalled caffe, and which was of same version. And now my error is resolved.